# How to instantiate a Forward class?

Tags: ios, forward-declaration, forward

I got a warning like  Attempting to use the forward class *** as superclass when i tried to set a third party class as superclass of my view controller.

How can I instantiate this class or use as a superclass of my class ?

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your error will occur in this example:

MyClass.h:

```
@class SuperDuperClass;

@interface MyClass : SuperDuperClass

@end
```

The fix is to let the compiler see the class definition by including its header file:

```
#import "SuperDuperClass.h"

@interface MyClass : SuperDuperClass

@end
```

That's about as specific as I can get with the little information provided in your question.